# which one between XGBoost and neural networks is more interpretable?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, interpretation, boosting, explainable-ai

I have heard people say, "One of the disadvantages of neural networks is that they are generally less interpretable". But I wonder, how is another model, such as XGBoost, more interpretable than neural networks? In XGBoost, one could use feature importance, SHAP, or PDP to explain the model, which I believe can also apply to neural networks?

Comment: It probably depends on the context in which you found that quote, and in particular what "traditional ML" is. Neural networks have been around far longer than XGBoost, so I don't quite see why XGBoost would be "more traditional" than NNs. It's quite possible that for your quote, "traditional ML" refers to regression, GAMs etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I now see the confusion and have updated the question, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both (sufficiently large) neural networks and XGBoost are not interpretable on their own (they are not "intrinsically interpretable") and are [typically](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42256-019-0048-x) [seen](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3359786) as part of the same "not interpretable" category. Both can be interpreted post-hoc using various methods such as feature importance, SHAP, PDP, [saliency maps](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9369420), [counterfactual explanations](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/counterfactual.html), etc.

As Stephan Kolassa already mentioned, the "more interpretable" traditional models neural networks are often compared with are much simpler models like logistic regression or simple (non-boosted, non-ensemble) decision trees. (These [often perform surprisingly well](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/582072/131402) when compared with modern neural networks in a proper evaluation. Even in image processing, logistic regression based on interpretable hand-crafted features [can very well outperform modern CNNs](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.01737).)

In a separate branch of research, there is [a push to make neural networks intrinsically interpretable](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42256-019-0048-x).

Comment: This answer is delightful. It's my honor to receive such a high-quality answer. Thanks, Eike!

Comment: @J21 happy to help! :-)